# Default position of new stroke changed

Tags: objects, shortcut, grease-pencil, units, object-mode

First image is where the default stroke appears in grease pencil

[image: Default Grease Pencil stroke position]

Second image is where the stroke appears now.

[image: Changed default position]

I really need help to reset this position. All new objects are appearing in the new position and it is very irritating. So please help me reset it to all 0.